# Do we need to be told to 'Have fun'?

Tags: discussion

This is just a small irritation, but there seem to be a number of questions that end with the instruction to 'Have fun!'. I understand that it's just the asker's way of being nice, but can we treat these like the 'Thank you' gets treated on StackOverflow and edit them to delete? This is a site for recreational programming, so I'm here to have fun. If I don't think I will have fun answering a question I'll probably give it a miss.

I just seems a bit redundant. Or am I being terribly anal now?

Comment: I agree. You have my blessing to edit out such lines. :-D

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Mine too, as long as you have fun while doing so :-)

Comment: Is the [automagical stripper](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/212780) configurable per-site?

Comment: There are only [26 questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/180253) on this site at the moment that have the words "have fun" in them, including close questions. I'm sure nobody would mind if you edited them, although if it bothers you enough to come post about it here, perhaps you should heed the advice and have fun!

Comment: Perhaps the problem would be solved with a "have-fun" tag.  It would take up less space and make it easier to find these questions if you're really serious about having fun.

Comment: @Dr.Rebmu As Calvin from *Calvin and Hobbes* once said, "If you're *serious* about having fun, it isn't much fun at all."

Comment: @Geobits Please warn people before sending them to NSFW links. I can't be looking at magical strippers on a company laptop!!

Comment: why? you bored? forget this and just HAVE FUN !

Comment: Is this off-topic? It probably belongs in Inter Personal Skills ;)

Answer (score 3):

This reminds me of an anecdote I tell all the time. It used to be the case that cans of soda would have instructions stamped into the top of the can.

1. lift tab
2. push back
3. enjoy!

Now this has always appeared to me to be a sneaky way of disavowing responsibility. If I don't enjoy it, the manufacturer could theoretically tell me to try again and follow all the directions.

Comment: There are these instructions on the back of "Wet Nap"...little wipe cloths sealed in a pouch with some kind of soap in them.  The instructions said something like (1) tear package along line (2) unfold wet nap (3) use wet nap.  Good thing I finally read the directions and saw step 3, I'd just been unpacking them and unfolding them and had a big pile of them next to me...but my hands weren't any cleaner!

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a trite "have fun" then editing out seems fine, like editing off a signature or a "thanks in advance" or anything else wasting screen real estate.

But if it encodes some sort of definition of what fun is, and *"You know what would be really fun..."* and lays out some ideas for what properties an interesting solution might have, then that's different.

Good to axe the "end-of-paragraph, newline, new paragraph with redundant or no information".  But don't get in a fight about it.  Cite this meta post in the edit comment.  If the author cares enough about how they come across to put it back then let them.  To put another way: worth a fix but not a fight.

(On SO maybe the "Thanks in advance" warrants a policy fight for everyone's work efficiency, but not with this.)